# Error: Cannot set property 'onmousedown' of null - I am getting an Error if I want to set a property to an "getElementById" object

Tags: javascript, html

The answer to this Question will probably be really easy and obvious. I want to asign some values on a Buttonclick via JavaScript. I get the following Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmousedown' of null". I searched for maby 1 hour but didn't find anything.

The biggest problem is; THE EXACT SAME CODE WORKS ON A FIDDLE!!! https://jsfiddle.net/qnbdt2o9/

Am I missing something? I know, I could use JQuery, bit I want to do it in vanilla JS.

Does Someone see a Error in my Code?

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onmousedown = function(){
  var startFitness = document.getElementById('startFitness').value;
  var maxFitness = document.getElementById('maxFitness').value;
  var maxSpeed = document.getElementById('maxSpeed').value;
  var minSpeed = document.getElementById('minSpeed').value;
  var agility = document.getElementById('agility').value;

  cosAtt = [startFitness, maxFitness, maxSpeed, minSpeed, agility];
  console.log(cosAtt);
}
```

```html
<h4>Start Fitness <input type="text" id="startFitness"></h4>
<h4>Max Fitness <input type="text" id="maxFitness"></h4>
<h4>Max Speed <input type="text" id="maxSpeed"></h4>
<h4>Min Speed <input type="text" id="minSpeed"></h4>
<h4>Agility <input type="text" id="agility"></h4>

<button id="btn">+ Add</button>
```

EDIT:

I forgott to add a important Codeline to the question

Comment: this is your entire code ? there is no way this can work like this since btn is `null`, you need to do `btn = document.getElementById('btn');`

Comment: No. My entire code is maby 1000 cols.

Comment: You might be using `btn` before your button was loaded in DOM.

Comment: Is your `<script>` tag AFTER your `<body>` tag ? If you add your script in `<head>` then that's the cause of your problem because at that point `<body>` didn't load yet and the button doesn't exist.

Comment: You were right, This fixed my problem. I moved my Script-Tags to the bottom. Now it works. Thank you